# Passing data to functions in different modules (not explicitly)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, modular-design

My problem can be generalized by this example. I have a Jupter notebookfile, say main. ipynb and I am calling some functions  which are in a different notebook that I wrote.

#File name main.ipynb

Bunch of code and variable assignment of x,y,z and create arrays a,b,c

```
# Function call 

some_function(x,y,z):
    #Do bunch of operations on x,y,z and a,b,c but a,b,c are not passed to the function
    return result
```

My main notebook finds variables x,y,z but in addition also creates arrays a,b and c. These arrays are not passed to the function but are required by the function 'some_function' to run the code.

For reasons I wont go into, I can't also pass the arrays a,b and c.

What's the easiest way to make some_function in the other notebook aware of arrays a,b and c which are generated in my main notebook?

Am I better off not using notebooks and just .py files? What are the pros/cons of either? Any help is appreciated, thanks!